# Can I redirect a query from default search box in SharePoint to a different search engine

Tags: sharepoint, search, fast-esp

I dont want the default results that SharePoint returns. I want the query term when entered into SharePoint search box to be redirected to a different search engine? Can I do that. 
I have seen FAST ESP web parts but could not figure out how they actually transferred the query to FAST search engine.

Any help would be really appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Add a content editor to the main search page with the following line of code

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://newsearchserver">
```

To pass the querystring I don't have any code but I did a quick search and the following link provides information about how to get the querystring value.

http://blogs.edork.com/MikeGeyer/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=c6444f02-e1a0-4a5e-b6f4-70bccdc80508&ID=36

From there you should be able to put it together and redirect to another server with the proper querystring.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to customize the Google Search Appliance search box for sharepoint.
http://code.google.com/apis/searchappliance/documentation/connectors/200/connector_admin/searchbox_sharepoint.html

The source code it´s on:
http://code.google.com/p/google-enterprise-connector-sharepoint/downloads/list